# Background task of writing to the database by timer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-hosted-services

How to write to the database on a timer in the background. For example, check mail and add new letters to the database. In the example, I simplified the code just before writing to the database.

The class names from the example in Microsoft. 
The recording class itself:

```
namespace EmailNews.Services
{

internal interface IScopedProcessingService
{
    void DoWork();
}

internal class ScopedProcessingService : IScopedProcessingService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public ScopedProcessingService(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.Date = DateTime.Now;
        mail.Note = "lala";
        mail.Tema = "lala";
        mail.Email = "lala";
        _context.Add(mail);
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
}
```

Timer class:

```
namespace EmailNews.Services
{
#region snippet1
internal class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    public TimedHostedService(IServiceProvider services, ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
    {
        Services = services;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is starting.");

        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var scopedProcessingService =
                scope.ServiceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingService>();

            scopedProcessingService.DoWork();
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
#endregion
}
```

Startup:

```
        services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();
        services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService, ScopedProcessingService>();
```

It seems everything is done as in the example, but nothing is added to the database, which is not so?

Comment: Did you try debugging? Does the timer fire? Is the service's `DoWork` called? Does it complete or does it throw? Apart from debugging you should add logging to your code to log exceptions at least.

Comment: It's probably the fact that you don't `await` your `SaveChangesAsync` call, especially as the scope that produces your `IScopedProcessingService` and corresponding `ApplicationDbContext` instances is being disposed before that call completes.

Comment: The `Timer` class can't handle an async callback. `DoWork` *has* to be `async Task` to allow `SaveChangesAsync` to complete without blocking. This means you can't call it from a timer's callback. You could replace the timer with a a loop that contains a `Task.Delay()`.

Comment: Check Maarten Balliauw's article [Building a scheduled task in ASP.NET Core/Standard 2.0](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/08/01/building-a-scheduled-cache-updater-in-aspnet-core-2.html). The `ExecuteAsync` contains a loop that call the tasks inside a timer and then calls `await Task.Delay(...);`. The article goes a lot farther than that, allowing the definition of custom tasks, parsing `cron` schedule strings, executing multiple tasks at a time etc

Comment: David Fowler created a Github repo with async gotchas and warnings. Check the [Timer Callbacks](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#timer-callbacks) section for the proper way to call asynchronous callbacks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a rather interesting question, that boils down to "How do you correctly handle an async timer callback?"

The immediate problem is that `SaveChangesAsync` isn't getting awaited. The DbContext almost certainly gets disposed before `SaveChangesAsync` has a chance to run. To await it, `DoWork` must become an `async Task` method (never async void) :

```
internal interface IScheduledTask
{
    Task DoWorkAsync();
}

internal class MailTask : IScheduledTask
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public MailTask(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        var mail = new Mail 
                   { Date = DateTime.Now,
                     Note = "lala",
                     Tema = "lala",
                     Email = "lala" };
        _context.Add(mail);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

The problem now is how to call `DoWorkAsync` from the timer callback. If we just call it without awaiting, we'll get the *same* problem we had in the first place. A timer callback can't handle methods that return Task. We can't make it `async void` either, because this would result in the same problem - the method will return before any async operation has a chance to finish.

David Fowler explains how to properly handle asynchronous timer callbacks in the [Timer Callbacks](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#timer-callbacks) section of his [Async Guidance](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md)
 article :

```
private readonly Timer _timer;
private readonly HttpClient _client;

public Pinger(HttpClient client)
{
    _client = new HttpClient();
    _timer = new Timer(Heartbeat, null, 1000, 1000);
}

public void Heartbeat(object state)
{
    // Discard the result
    _ = DoAsyncPing();
}

private async Task DoAsyncPing()
{
    await _client.GetAsync("http://mybackend/api/ping");
}
```

The actual method should be `async Task` but the returned task only has to be *assigned*, not awaited, in order for it to work properly.

Applying this to the question leads to something like this :

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...
    _timer = new Timer(HeartBeat, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private void Heartbeat(object state)
{
    _ = DoWorkAsync();
}


private async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var schedTask = scope.ServiceProvider
                             .GetRequiredService<IScheduledTask>();

        await schedTask.DoWorkAsync();
    }
}
```

David Fowler explains why async void is [**ALWAY BAD** in ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#async-void) - it's not only that async actions won't be awaited, exceptions will crash the application.

He also explains why [we can't use](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#implicit-async-void-delegates) `Timer(async state=>DoWorkAsync(state))` - that's an `async void` delegate.